# How to configure KDE start menu to pop when pressing "Meta" key

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, kde, desktop, kubuntu

For an unknown reason the shortcut to display the desktop menu by pressing the `windows` key (aka. `meta` )<kbd>⊞</kbd> on the keyboard is not working anymore on KDE desktop.

So of course I can click on it or assign a shortcut, but it must be a combination of key (e.g <kbd>⊞</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, ...).

So my question is simple:
How do I force Kubuntu / KDE to react to the <kbd>⊞</kbd> key by displaying the menu ?

Is there a simple solution, like an option in the settings ?

---

- OS Version: Kubuntu 21.04
- KDE Version: 5.80